# Create Generic Nifi Flow for re usability purpose

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a nifi flow which extracts records from RDBMS (SQL Server) table and
put these on HDFS in parquet format. This flow will run several times in a day to get delta records from source table. Now I need to replicate this same process for 100+ different source tables. So rather than creating 100+ nifi flows for each separate table, can I create main flow (let's say template) and pass parameter like source extract sql, target file name etc to main flow  and repeat these steps for each source table. I am using Nifi Nifi 1.7. I am pretty close to parameterizing the flow itself.

Example-
Parameterizing the parameters in the components used in the flow. Example- Filename = ${path}/${filename}

Not sure how to pass values to this flow from command line?

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: you could create the first step of your process as [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/), in the body pass the tablename or even json with different parameters... then from command line with `curl` you can start new instance of your flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pass parameters using a command line.. But you can use a listener(For example: [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/)) and then use the FlowFile's attributes as parameters.

Another option is to use the variable registry to register those parameters, then use it as a NiFi template. Then, you can use NiFi's [Rest API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) to deploy this template many times using different parameters.